# HttpClient java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while trying run jar

Tags: java, ant, jar, compilation, httpclient

I have exception like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.cli
ent.DefaultHttpClient.execute(Lorg/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest;)Lo
rg/apache/http/client/methods/CloseableHttpResponse;
```

When I try to run jar with command

```
java -cp C:\Users\andrew\\lib\*;. -jar selenium4j-transform.jar -mode=selenium -restfulprops=restfulprops.properties
```

I don't understand FROM IDEA everything runs just fine, AFTER COMPILE USING `ANT` I try to run and exception occurs.
I even use same jars:

```
<include name="httpclient-4.4.1.jar"/>
<include name="httpcore-4.4.1.jar"/>
```

I cheaked jar and I have those classes

Please help

Comment: Can you post your ant build script?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium jar also contains DefaultHttpClient in it. Hence ant executor confuses while execution.

Do mention latest jar in the library jars and make sure  should mention before selenium jar